# Understand order of magnitude performance gap between python and C++ for CPU heavy application

Tags: python, c++, performance

**Summary: ** I observe a ~1000 performance gap between a python code and a C+ code doing the same job despite the use of parallelization, vectorization, just in time compilation and machine code conversion using Numba in the context of scientific calculation. CPU wont be used at full, and I don't understand why

Hello everybody,

I just started in a laboratory doing simulation of various material, including simulation of the growth of biological-like tissues. To do that we create a 3D version of said tissue (collection of vertices stored in a numpy array) and we apply different functions on it to mimic physic/biology.

We have a C++ code doing just that, which takes approximately 10 second to run. Someone converted said code to python, but this version takes about 2h30 hours to process. We tried every trick in the book we knew to accelerate the code. We used numba to accelerate numpy where appropriate, parallelized the code as much as we could, tried to vectorize what could be, but still the gap remains. In fact the earlier version of the code took days to proceed.

When the code execute, multiple cores are properly used, as monitored using the build-in system monitor. However, they are not used at full, and in fact deactivating cores manually does not seem to hit performances too much. At first I thought it could be due to the GIL, but releasing it had no effect on performances either. Somehow it makes me think of a bottleneck in memory transfer between the CPU and the ram, but I cannot understand why the C version would not have the same problem. I also have the feeling that there is a performance cost for calling functions. One of my earlier tasks was to refactor the code, thus decomposing complicated functions into smaller elements. I since have a small performance degradation compared to the earlier version.

I must say I am really wondering where my bottleneck is and how it could be tested/improved. Any idea would be very welcome.

I am aware my question is kind of a complicated one, so let me know if you would need additional information, I would be happy to provide.

Comment: Is it the same algorithm? Are the same types of data structures used?

Comment: You have **profiler** to spot where time is taken. then you might show us the 2 equivalent code if you need more precise help.

Comment: Without a segment of the code which is especially slow on Python and for comparison the C++ version and a relevant example (including inputs), this question is hard to impossible to answer. It could be various things which slows down the computation drastically.

Comment: FYI, Python is an interpretive language that calls libraries that are written in C or C++.  Thus having Python faster than C or C++ a bit of a curiosity.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The algorithm is not exactly the same, as it was adapted to python where possible, but is fairly close. Data structure is different though, the C version uses vector classes to represent 3D arrays, whereas the python version uses numpy. I did profile the code and identify a few problematic functions, unfortunately they are several dozens line of code each...